# Synchronize ReduxForm fields state update

Tags: redux-form

I have several fields in `ReduxForm` and I want all of them to react to each other updating how they look when one of the fields is changed. For instance, I have `radio button group` and a `select` field. When I select some value from select field, correct radio button should be switched to. How could I achieve such binding? I tried setting `name` parameter to the same value for both fields but it did not work. Unfortunately I can not use their `Fields` parameter since the project is set up this way already architecturally to use solely `Field`. So, I need a way of binding several fields into one by a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case I was able to achieve the desired behavior by supplying `value` to the `Select` (`Dropdown` `ReduxForm Field` type), so that when it is rerendered (which is caused by the interaction with `radio button group`), the value gets updated. The `onChange` method triggered on `Select` was passing new `state` up in the hierarchy which triggered `radio button group` update. So, from `Select` interaction `radio button group` was updated by changes in actual `state`, but the other way round, from `radio button group` interaction, `Select` was just rerendered with the new value (`radio buttons bounded`) passed to it since `state` was updated.